# Identical codes acting differently in CG and JS?

Tags: glsl, gpu, cg, hsv

I have an RGBtoHSV code written in CG to preview color changes that are then written to file using the same code in JS.

First of all, i have to add 0.33 to the H value, to get results almost the same in both codes. Why would i have to add 0.33, specifically? what different function/ rounding difference could this point towards on the graphics card?

even then, 66 percent of the picture has precisely the same color on both codes, and 33 percent of the colors are different. I dont understand why?

if i take out the 3 if conditions, the codes have the same result without needing to add 0.33 anywhere.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sry. I have narrowed it down to the HSV.x, it ends up comletely different in both functions. the y and z are ok.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i have found that the first variable that has different results is Delta. delta is completely different in both functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Delta.xyz -= Delta.zxy;
```

is different from:

```
    Delta.x -= del.z;
    Delta.y -= del.x;
    Delta.z -= del.y;
```

because the CG version does it all in one, whereas the JS version overwrites itself. it should be:

```
    var del = Delta;
    Delta.x -= del.z;
    Delta.y -= del.x;
    Delta.z -= del.y;
```

I can't beleive i read that line over 20 times and never found it was the error.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that I see as a possible problem is the different behavior of % operator in Javascript for negative numbers, compared to fract.

You should replace it with fract(x) = x - Math.floor(x):

```
HSV.x = HSV.x/6;
HSV.x -= Math.floor(HSV.x);
```